# Kendo MVC Grid Custom Command Font Awesome Icon using Helper

Tags: font-awesome, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm stuck on a problem. I am using Kendo MVC and want to display font awesome icon in Grid Custom commands.
I have defined Grid Custom Commands for Edit, Delete, and Detail.

```
columns.Command(command =>
{
    command.Custom("Edit").Action("Edit", "User");
    command.Custom("Details").Action("Details", "User");
    command.Custom("Delete").Action("Delete", "User");
}
```

Please review the following screenshot. I want to auto-add the `fa fa-edit` and other icons using MVC Helper extension method.

[image]

Comment: I just answered a very similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43329397/integrating-fontawesome-into-kendoui-css/43330751#43330751)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to override the CSS for the edit/details/delete command buttons which gives you the option to apply the same style for all pages or just one, for example:

```
.k-grid-content .k-button.k-grid-edit::before {
    content: "\f044" !important;
}
.k-grid-content .k-button.k-grid-delete::before {
    content: "\f1f8" !important;
}
```

And when grid transitions (after placed into `edit` mode):

```
.k-grid-content .k-button.k-grid-update::before {
    content: "\f044" !important;
}
.k-grid-content .k-button.k-grid-cancel::before {
    content: "\f1f8" !important;
}
```

Here is the a complete [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ETIYa/11) and [all Font Awesome icons along with their CSS values](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/).

Comment: I want to work these with Grid Column Custom Commands. The sample you gave is only for edit/delete commands

Comment: Well then just change the name of the `button` from `.k-grid-edit`, `.k-grid-delete` to the name of your button(s)..

Comment: This is causing double icons to appear on my buttons.  The built in icon is not being replaced and the Font Awesome icon is showing up next to it.  Any ideas how I can resolve this?