# Kendo MVC Grid - Edit and Delete Command Icons are Too Wide

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo MVC Grid that has the following edit and delete command buttons.

[image]

The code looks like this:

```
    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit().Text("&nbsp;"); command.Destroy().Text("&nbsp;"); }).Width(86);
```

As you can see, the box each icon is in is way too big and takes up unnecessary space. I'd like to keep the icons but just shrink the space they consume. Can I do this?

Comment: It should scale to the size of the "text" inside the button.  If you remove the custom width it should remove the white space on the buttons.  All my grids have it scale this way.

Comment: You could use font awesome like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43329397/integrating-fontawesome-into-kendoui-css)

Comment: @Kevin - If I remove the custom width (Width(86)), the cell doesn't display at all. And, if I shrink the width any further, but still greater than 0, it simply wraps the two icons and creates two lines. Could you possibly show me your markup code?

Comment: ```columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }); 
                           columns.Command(command => { command.Custom("View PDF").Click("openPDF"); });```  Here is one example of what I have for it.  It automatically scales for each button, if I increase the length of the View PDF it correctly matches the size.  Do you have the newest version of Telerik?  Maybe it was a more recent update?

Comment: Upon comparing to mine, it looks like your Pencil and Delete (Edit and Delete) are scaled to the length of the words, not the image of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, you should leave the captions visible for accessibility reasons. Screen readers users won't know what button does what otherwise.